# Return a count of the number of rows per column containing numbers

Tags: text-processing

I've tried working with answers from this question, but am having trouble adapting it my specific needs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005013/count-the-number-of-rows-per-column-in-bash-shell

My goal is to write a bash script that reads in a csv file, and return a count for each column. The count would be the amount of rows containing numerical values (including dash, periods, and colons).

Given a csv file like this:

```
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3.2,NA,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,Bad,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,NA,9.7,P
```

I'm expecting my result to be:

```
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

Comment: but why period `.`, these are all valid floating point numbers, `9.7`, `3.2`, or even `-1`, `-1.7` if you can have these in your inputs. so why dash `-`?

Comment: `numerical values (including dash, periods, and colons)` would mean that `foo.com` or `bad-example` would be counted as numerical values. Is that REALLY what you want or do you actually want to count a field if it contains at least 1 digit or starts and/or ends with a digit or something else? Please [edit] your question to include cases that contains digits, dash, periods, and colons that should NOT be counted as it's always easy to match the strings you want but harder to not match similar strings you don't want.

Comment: That CSV file is woefully underquoted, and as it's in such bad shape, I'm wondering what will happen when these solutions encounter a properly quoted CSV file, where one can embed commas into the values because the values are surrounded by quote strings.

Comment: Will there be columns with mixed alpha and numeric characters? Wouldn't it just be easiest to exclude columns with alpha characters from your count? Or do you expect one-or-more columns to contain **only** punctuation characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could do it.

```bsh
perl -sF, -lane 'my $i;
  $s[$i++] += /^\h*\d/ for @F;
  }{print @s;
' -- -,=, yourfile.csv
```

---

GNU sed + rs + awk + paste utilities:

```bsh
sed -E '
  s/(^|,)[0-9][^,]*/\11/g
  s/(^|,)[^0-9,]*/\10/g
' yourfile.csv |
rs -Tc,  |
awk '{print gsub(/1/,"")}'|
paste -sd, -
```

---

```bsh
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
    s[i] += $i ~ /^ *[0-9]/
}
END {
  for (i=1; i in s; i++)
    printf "%s%s", s[i], \
      (i+1 in s) ? OFS : ORS
}' yourfile.csv
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the great answer- Is there a way to edit the general expression to include negative numbers as well? AKA "-54.4"

Comment: Specifically in relation to the last code block using "awk" as that is what worked best for me

Comment: In that scenario change the regex to the following:`$i ~ /^ *-?[0-9]/` which shall look for an optional dash just before the first digit. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
   { gsub(/[:. -]/, ""); for(c=1; c<=NF; c++) if($c==$c+0) count[c]++ }
END{ for(i=1; i<c; i++) printf "%d%s", count[i], (i+1<c?OFS:ORS) }' infnile
```

Output:

```
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

Comment: Note that `$c == $c + 0` may return true for things like `inf`, `0xf`, `1e2` (which may or may not be wanted by the OP). With GNU `awk`, you'll see some variation if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could test each comma-separated field with a regular expression (to see if it contains a decimal digit for example). Turn that into an element-wise indicator and make a running count.

For example using perl:

```
$ perl -F, -MList::MoreUtils=pairwise -lne '
  BEGIN{@c = ()}
  @ind = map { scalar $_ =~ /\d/ } @F; @c = pairwise { $a + $b } @c, @ind
  }{
  print join ",", @c
' file
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

A similar approach should be straightforward in awk - you would just need to loop over elements explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to get the expected output you posted from the sample input you posted is:

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS=',' '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i] += ($i ~ /[0-9]/) }
    END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d%s", c[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) }
' file
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

but maybe what you really want is:

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS=',' '
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) c[i] += ($i ~ /^[0-9]([0-9.: -]*[0-9])?$/) }
    END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d%s", c[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS) }
' file
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

or something else?

If neither of those are what you need then please edit your question to provided clearer requirements and better sample input/output that covers all of the cases that you do NOT want to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my $a; for [Z] lines.map(*.subst(" ", :global).split(",")) { 
      $a.push: m:g/ [\d+ % <[-:.]>]+ /.elems }; say $a.join(",");'
```

Sample Input:

```
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3.2,NA,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,Bad,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,5,9,P
2012-01-01 12:01:01, 1,3,NA,9.7,P
```

Sample Output:

```
5,5,4,3,5,0
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. First a scalar `$a` is declared. Then briefly, `lines` are read in and internal whitespace is handled, simply by `map`-ping into the input and deleting whitespace using `subst` (substituting with nothing). Then each element (line) is `split` on `,` commas, thus breaking rows into columns.

After completing the first `lines.map(*.subst(" ", :global).split(","))` operation, columns and rows are swapped with Raku's `[Z]` "zip" operator, which successively pulls off the elements of a denoted list (say all elements comprising the first column of a table), and combines them, continuing until elements at one position in the list are depleted.

Then each column-wise elements are tested against a regex that seeks matches with `\d` digits separated-by (using Raku's `%` modified-quantifier) a custom character class containing `-`, or `:`, or `.`.  Each columnwise match is Boolified to `True` with `.so`, and `elems` elements are summed, then `push`-ed onto the `$a` scalar.  Finally the result is returned with `say`.

Two issues of note:

1. There's certainly an alternative way to handle internal whitespace other than what I've shown (TMTOWTDI), for example, using Raku's `:s` "sigspace" regex adverb.
2. The input text can be processed using shorter code and/or without saving to a Raku variable. Example code below (however--returns counts linewise):

```perl
raku -e 'for [Z] lines.map(*.subst(" ", :global).split(",")) { 
      say m:g/ [\d+ \% <[-:.]>]+ /.elems };'
```

Sample Output:

```
5
5
4
3
5
0
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Modified_quantifier:_%,_%%
https://raku.org